# Illegal state exception. Activity unable to start because of toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am trying to add an actionbar similar to soundclouds. I am following the instructions on how to customize the action bar on the [android developer](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) website. The error seems to be that the action bar is already being supplied but I am trying to create another one.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

Here is **onCreate()**:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
addBirthdayFragment();
```

Here is the **layout** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried to just remove the xml code and java code for the toolbar, in the layout and onCreate respectively, however this is not working; the same error still persists. It must be something to do with the theme I am using, but I do not know what exactly. It confuses me because the theme is the default one so I did not expect this.

Here is my **theme**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**Side question:**

I am trying to achieve the look of the soundcloud action bar, which appears to be tabbed. Is this the way I should go if I want [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.soundcloud.android&hl=en) result, or is there some other widget that is used for tabbed action bars?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is complaining because you never told it that you will use a Toolbar instead of the Android-provided ActionBar. To let Android know about this, you need to add these to your style:

```
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

If you'd like to use the Android ActionBar sometimes and a Toolbar of yours some other time, you can add the above two lines to a new style extending your AppTheme, and using that on AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<!-- Use this one in the Manifest when you want to use the native ActionBar -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- your styling here -->
</style>

<!-- Use this one when you want to implement your own Toolbar -->
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for marking my answer as the right one :) As for the ActionBar tabs, you can check this: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabs

Answer (score 0):

Your code is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

The line `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` says dark action bar. you need to change it to NoActionBar.

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Worked perfectly.

Comment: You are most welcome. Please accept the answer so that others can see it on top.